# OpenGL SetPixel with a fragment shader

Tags: opengl, shader, pixel, rgba

So, I'm trying to modify a specific pixel of a sprite. Currently I've made it work by creating myself a `SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)` function. It works by modifying texture's info(RGBA values) and than passing it to a sprite. But this is slow:

1. Using CPU instead of GPU where (I HOPE) I could use shaders to improve my performance.
2. I have to re-upload modified texture every time I modify a single pixel.

This question is big to me. How do I use shaders in order to modify a specific pixel? I only can modify color per Vertex which is not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Fragment Shader modifies all the pixels in a framebuffer (when you call drawElements or drawArrays), not just a single pixel. If the new color value is in your CPU program, you can either upload it to the GPU texture, or set it as a constant variable in your fragment shader.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to modify multiple pixels at once? Uploading 1 pixel to the GPU is equally complex as uploading 1000000 pixels.

Comment: Suggestion: delete your `SetPixel` function and figure out how to do what you do without it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have to upload all texture and after every pixel update. You can cache changes and update smallest rectangle with `glCopyTextSubImage`.

If you really want to try GPU updates, you can use compute shaders (however, some old hardware doesn't support them) or bind your texture data as SSBO and write directly to it without using separate framebuffer object.